# How do I reference Postgres constraints in j00q?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

Using jooq 3.11.8, referencing a constraint in an `onConflictOnConstraint` is not particularly discoverable, and the documentation is exactly no help.  I know the name of the constraint, but `onConflictOnConstraint` doesn't take a `String`.

Specifically:

```
ctx.insertInto(
  TABLE,
  TABLE.ID,
  TABLE.FIELD1
)
.values(
  id,
  value
)
.onConflictOnConstraint(/* WHAT GOES HERE? */)
.doUpdate()
.set(TABLE.FIELD1, value)
.execute();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 overloads of this method:

- [`onConflictOnConstraint(Constraint)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertOnDuplicateStep.html#onConflictOnConstraint-org.jooq.Constraint-): Use this with constraints defined through [`DSL.constraint()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#constraint-org.jooq.Name-), i.e. the DDL API
- [`onConflictOnConstraint(Name)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertOnDuplicateStep.html#onConflictOnConstraint-org.jooq.Name-): Use this with [`DSL.name()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#name-java.lang.String-), a way to create ad hoc identifier references
- [`onConflictOnConstraint(UniqueKey)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertOnDuplicateStep.html#onConflictOnConstraint-org.jooq.UniqueKey-): Use this with generated `UniqueKey` references in generated tables, e.g. as obtained from [`Table.getPrimaryKey()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html#getPrimaryKey--)

Comment: Thanks a lot, man.  I would suggest that some small example of how to create and use `Name` objects would be a really helpful addition to jooq's documentation, because I spent _way_ too long just trying to figure out how to create one.  Maybe a static factory method on `Name` or something would make it more discoverable (I'm just spitballing here).

Comment: @LeeCrabtree: Almost everything can be created from `org.jooq.impl.DSL`. In fact, you will ideally just `import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;` in every class where you use jOOQ and just start typing things like `name("abc")`. But point taken, we should point to those `DSL` methods from each individual `org.jooq.XYZ` type to help new users discover these methods. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8240

Comment: I've been using jOOQ for something like a year and half now, and this was the first time I ever ran across `Name`.  I think jOOQ is awesome, I just get frustrated when a feature isn't as discoverable as it could be.  Sorry if all this came across as angry or accusatory; that absolutely was not my intention.

Comment: @LeeCrabtree: No worries at all. But how else can we improve things, now that you know what `Name` is, and how to construct it? How could the documentation have been changed to help you discover this?

Comment: My ultimate problem was trying to do an upsert where the conflicting constraint wasn't the primary key.  It's not the most common thing in the world, but more real-world examples would be a good thing.  Right now the documentation seems largely like just Javadocs, which are useful for knowing WHAT something is, but not always HOW to use it.

Comment: @LeeCrabtree: I see your point. This would be quite a bit of work to review throughout the entire manual. May I refer you to the PostgreSQL manual for the time being, given that jOOQ's syntax matches pretty much all of the PostgreSQL syntax

Comment: Oh, I wasn't trying to suggest that this is a glaring defect in documentation that needs to be solved immediately if jOOQ is to be useful to anyone.  I was trying to say that the documentation is heavier on API contracts than it is on examples, which is totally the kind of thing that has to happen over time.  I think good documentation needs both, and that's something I've struggled with finding with regards to jOOQ.

Comment: @LeeCrabtree: Thanks for the feedback. Indeed, there could be more examples, I totally agree. Do note my saying *"for the time being"*, which is another way of saying, *"here's a workaround you could use right now"*. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @LeeCrabtree: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8255 has been implemented for jOOQ 3.12, improving the Javadoc of most `org.jooq.XYZ` types with a little more explanation as well as an example. Thanks again for your feedback!